# $(...).dialog is not a function: can't track the source of jQuery error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, telerik

Some time ago, I wrote a code to show partial view as a popup window. In that old case, I wrote html and javascript from scratch and it worked.

For this I am using "dialog".

```
        $('#UserChangePassword').dialog({
            zIndex: 9998,
            modal: true,
            draggable: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: ['center', 'center'],
            show: 'blind',
            hide: 'blind',
            width: 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $("span.ui-dialog-title").dir = "rtl";
                $("span.ui-dialog-title").text("משתמש פורטל")
                //if (callback != undefined) {
                //    callback()
                //}
            },
            close: function () {

            }
        });
    }
```

However, now when I am trying to add the same feature (pop-up) in existing code, written earlier by someone else, I get an error "$(...).dialog is not a function".

I already tried doing some research on it, from what I understand it can be caused either by jQuery not loaded at all, or jQuery loaded more then once.

**HTML from code that works - main window has this:**

```
<script>
    src = "/Scripts/old_script.js"
</script>

@section ClientScripts{
<link href="../../Assets/Css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/Telerik/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/old_script.js"></script>

@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).Scripts(group => group.AddSharedGroup("SharedScripts")
                                                        .AddSharedGroup("TelerikScripts")
                                                        .AddSharedGroup("InvoicesScripts")))

<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/Start.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911/extended/ExtendedControls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
html goes here
</div>

<div id="ChangePassword" style="position: center; display:none">
    @Html.Partial("ChangePassword")
</div>
```

**HTML from code that works - partial view: (yes it uses telerik too and it works)**

```
@section ClientScripts
{
    @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).Scripts(group => group.AddSharedGroup("SharedScripts")
                                                            .AddSharedGroup("TelerikScripts")
                                                            .AddSharedGroup("TerminalWorkstationScripts")))
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<div>
htmll goes here
</div>
```

**The main window of where I want to add this:**

```
@section ClientScripts
    {
        @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true).Scripts(group => group.AddSharedGroup("SharedScripts")
                                                                .AddSharedGroup("TelerikScripts")
                                                                .AddSharedGroup("WorkstationScripts")))
    }
```

And **separately** from it:

```
    @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false).OnDocumentReady(@"twCreatePopup.init();twCreatePopup.whenPopupEnter();"))

<script src="/Scripts/Tools/Tabs.js"></script>
```

It seems that the one who worked on this before me, had his own way with showing popups, hence those functions. I prefer to NOT touch his part, just to allow my code to work together with his.

**Can the reason be, that here Telerik scripts are loaded/accessed twice?
Maybe they can be merged to one command?**

**What I tried:**

1. Adding Telerik block to partial window html, tried with it and without - no change
2. Tried copying the whole ClientScripts block from old main window to new one, tried to comment/un-comment part of lines - no change
3. Disabling one of Telerik script declaration in html of new window - obviously it causes problems with existing code
4. Tried to call function itself in javascript in two ways:

   ```
    $('#Button').click(function ()
    {
        alert(document.getElementById('ConfirmCode').dialog);

        $('#ConfirmCode').dialog.dialog('open');
    }
   ```

And like this:

```
$(function ()
    {
        $("#ConfirmCode").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false
            });

        $("#Button").click(function ()
        {
            alert(1);
            $("#ConfirmCode").dialog('open');
        });
    });
```

The error still exists.

5. Using "$.noConflict()"

Here results were most weird.
I tried using them in both versions of functions, before function name or inside of it, before "dialog open" command.
It still doesn't show popup window, but in addition to it either: Opens a new window with some kind of error written in json format or the pre-made (not mine) pop-up function seem to infinitely run again and again - this I see in "inspect". In the second case everything gets stuck and I have to reload the page.

6. I tried placing the "click" function that should open the pop-up inside "init" function and outside of it, it only works from inside.

What can cause the same code to work in one case, but not the other?

If it's jQuery, how I can track the problem, is it loaded twice or not loaded at all?

Please help!

Comment: dialog is [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) so check it is loaded. It is not enough to load jQuery

Comment: That's what I am asking - how and where I can track if it is loaded? I didn't find it via Inspect.

Comment: Inspect, network tab

Comment: Make sure jQuery UI is loaded AFTER jQuery

Comment: It seems it is loaded in code I wrote from scratch, but doesn't load in code where I am adding it to existing one. Even if I am using same block in html.

Comment: @mplungjan The mine code uses this one: "jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css", while existing one uses this instead: " jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css". What causes this?

Comment: They are not related. fancybox is a plugin not related to jQuery UI. Also why on earth are you using `ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/beta/0911` from what 2011 or earlier?? Is this `MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation` or somthing? It is using jQuery 1.6 as far as I can see

Comment: jQuery UI is on version 1.13.2: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

Comment: jQuery is 3.7.1 `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @mplungjan I tried adding those to "ClientScripts" block, instead of those I have now, only leaving Telerik, but it still doesn't load. I can't understand, why it isn't loaded?

Comment: Can it be caused by Telerik appearing twice in html? Maybe Telerik loads jquery-ui twice?

Comment: Look in the console. Go to network, Click on the , then reload the page. You need to see the jQuery.....js and jQuery-ui...js once. Then right-click, view source and search for .js - make sure none of the files without jquery in the file name actually also loads jquery

Comment: Well, I see here two types of lines, just one Telerik line: "script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/Scripts/Telerik/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>" and a few jquery lines about like this "<script type="text/javascript" src="/Assets/Scripts/jQuery/jquery.tipsy.js"></script>".

Comment: So the version of jQuery is ancient. What else is loaded from assets? I see `<script src="../../Assets/Scripts/jQuery/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>` in the top of your post, is that not loaded in the actual new page? then youhave your answer

Comment: jquery not loaded -> `$ is not defined`.  So jquery is loaded.  jquery-ui not loaded -> `$(..).dialog() not a function`.   loading jquery, then jquery-ui, then jquery again effectively "unloads" jquery-ui as it's not in the last loaded jquery.  So: either jquery-ui not loaded at all, or jquery loaded after jquery-ui (even if also before jquery-ui)

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I know jquery-ui should be loaded before jquery, that is how it appears in old, working code that does work. But it seems not to load on new AT ALL.

Comment: "*jquery-ui should be loaded before jquery*" - is that what you meant? Or typo?   Sounds like you're just missing the ui.js in your new page (as per @mplungjan comment above)

Comment: Code from page that works is shown in original post. I am trying to use same one in a new place, but it doesn't work. Yes, I understand I am missing something related to "jquery-ui" but how I can check and fix that?

Comment: I see `@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().jQuery(false)` but I do not see `scripts.AddGroup("HeaderScript", group => group
            .Add("~/Scripts/jquery-????.min.js")`

Comment: So one of these loads jQuery? `group.AddSharedGroup("SharedScripts") .AddSharedGroup("TelerikScripts").AddSharedGroup("InvoicesScripts")))`

Comment: Thank you both for your wish to help, but I am abandoning this question. I'll use a different approach to get what I need, without using popup. I really apologize for your lost time.